# Notepad++ Tab bar icons for different file types

Tags: notepad++

EditPad Lite has a feature where it shows the icons of the associated application for each file on the tab.  (ex. an html file shows the chrome icon, a txt file shows the notepad icon, etc.  See http://www.editpadlite.com/screens/editpadlite.png for a screenshot.)

Is there anyway to get NotePad++ to do the same?

Comment: Not that I can see. Looks like a good candidate for a feature request.
EDIT: Looks like someone requested it alreaady!
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3149712&group_id=95717&atid=612385

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye for future implementation then.